# Error Handling in System.Net.HttpWebRequest::GetResponse()

Tags: .net, powershell, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I have a Powershell script that uses `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` to communicate with a remote host.

I create the request, set properties accordingly and call `getresponse()` and `getresponsestream()` to read the entire response from the server to a string.  This works fine as long as the server responds with a "200 OK" message.

If the server responds with a "400 Bad Request" or any other error code, `getresponse()` and `getresponsestream()` throw exceptions and return nothing. My problem is there is more detailed error information included in the response header which I need so I can do my own error handling.

How would I be able to retrieve this 400 Bad Request signal?

Comment: Have you already caught the exception object and looked at the $_.Exception.Message property? And explored the $_.Exception object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit**: I misunderstood the question at first, but it turns out that you can retrieve the response header by using the `HttpWebResponse.GetResponseHeader()` method. If an exception occurs, the `HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()` method returns `$null`, and you have to use this code to retrieve the HttpWebResponse object, so that you can call `GetResponseHeader()` on it:

```
# If an exception occurs, get the HttpWebResponse object from the WebException object
$HttpWebResponse = $Error[0].Exception.InnerException.Response;
```

---

I'm pretty sure you'll want to stick with the `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` instead of the `System.Net.WebClient` object. Here is an example, similar to what you probably already have:

```
# Create a HttpWebRequest using the Create() static method
$HttpWebRequest = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create("http://www.google.com/");

# Get an HttpWebResponse object
$HttpWebResponse = $HttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

# Get the integer value of the HttpStatusCode enumeration
Write-Host -Object $HttpWebResponse.StatusCode.value__;
```

The GetResponse() method returns a `HttpWebResponse` object, which has a property named `StatusCode`, which points to a value in the `HttpStatusCode` .NET enumeration. Once you get a reference to the enumeration, we use the `value__` property to get the integer that is associated with the returned enum value.

If you get a null value from the `GetResponse()` method, then you'll want to read the most current error message in your catch {..} block. The `Exception.ErrorRecord` property should be the most helpful.

```
try {
  $HttpWebResponse = $null;
  $HttpWebRequest = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create("http://www.asdf.com/asdf");
  $HttpWebResponse = $HttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
  if ($HttpWebResponse) {
    Write-Host -Object $HttpWebResponse.StatusCode.value__;
    Write-Host -Object $HttpWebResponse.GetResponseHeader("X-Detailed-Error");
  }
}
catch {
  $ErrorMessage = $Error[0].Exception.ErrorRecord.Exception.Message;
  $Matched = ($ErrorMessage -match '[0-9]{3}')
  if ($Matched) {
    Write-Host -Object ('HTTP status code was {0} ({1})' -f $HttpStatusCode, $matches.0);
  }
  else {
    Write-Host -Object $ErrorMessage;
  }

  $HttpWebResponse = $Error[0].Exception.InnerException.Response;
  $HttpWebResponse.GetResponseHeader("X-Detailed-Error");
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx

Comment: The 3 digit HTTP status code does nothing for me. I need to access custom header "X-Detailed-Error" from the remote host's response. Isn't there some way to invoke getresponse() and have it return a webresponse object regardless of what the status code is?

Comment: I've updated the example. In the case of an exception occurring, you have to grab the `HttpWebResponse` object by using: `$Error[0].Exception.InnerException.Response`, and then you can call the `GetResponseHeader("X-Detailed-Error");` method.

Answer (score 0):

Ever tried the try and catch statements? This works fine for me.

ex:

```
$webclient = new-object system.net.webclient
try {
    $domain = $webclient.downloadstring("http://xrsolis.com") # get a non existent domain
} catch {
    write-host "domain inaccessible"
}
```

Comment: That doesn't really help because it doesn't let me access the full response from the server. After the server sends the common HTTP status code it also sends a custom header (X-Detailed-Error) with the exact reason why the request was not processed. I need to be able to access that header. $_.Exception returns the same exception message that I would see in the console with no catch statement (
Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.")